# Windows Server 2012 can be remote by mstsc but failed to ping

Tags: windows

I setup a new server with windows server 2012 system to do a server migration. I can remote the server via mstsc. But failed to ping the server. The server can ping outside successfully. My computer and server are not in the same lan.

I started the echo recall ipv4-in service. But it didn't work.

I have no idea about how to enable the ping on my sever.
I would appreciate it if anyone can give some suggestion about how to make me ping the server successfully.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: 1. Turn off the firewall and try ping again 2. ping the server from another server in the same subnet.

Comment: firewall was turned off once the server was setup. Only one server in the lan. So can't have this try.

Comment: Are you sure it's caused by the server, Windows by default enabled the firewall and block echo, that's most of the case, however, you disabled windows firewall as described, so the case could be on the gateway blocking  ICMP packages.

Comment: Any suggestion to make it unblocked by ICMP packages?

Comment: That's the reason I asked u to perform the ping from the same subnet. Once confirmed it's due to network policy, you can talk to the network guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing any issue with remote Desktop(MSTSC), first of all, you have to ensure that MSTSC is enabled in your client machine as well as server
If MSTSC is enabled in both then check in the server there is a policy on sever who can access via remote Desktop(This policy is about RDP version which version of MSTSc can access the server remotely select the lower version which is having in your client.

For getting ping first you have to ensure that  both (Client  machine & Server machine Should be in the same network it applicable when you are accessing the server locally )
Also once you check the firewall setting in your client machine if the firewall is enabled, then if possible then disable the firewall of the client machine if not possible then allow the ICMP Protocol in the firewall rule.

Once you have done all these steps your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you  for you suggestion. But I think the ping function don't need to both client & server machine in the same network because you can ping any website which server machine absolute are not in your lan. The firewall on both client and server machine is turned off. I think there is nothing related to the firewall.